# Upload Excel file with Japanese font

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, exceldatareader, cjk

I have a Japanese Excel ('.xls') file, I need to upload it to server using `IExcelDataReader`. below is my code:

```
IExcelDataReader reader;
DataSet dataSet = null;
if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
{
    // .xlsx
    reader =        ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(file.InputStream);
}
else if (fileExtension == ".xls")
{
    // .xls
    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(file.InputStream);
}
else
{
    response.Error =
        string.Format(Extensions.LabelFor(labelModels, null, 42), file.FileName);
    return response;
}
// cast to data set
dataSet = reader.AsDataSet();
DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[sheetName];
```

But I can not get Japanese values. Everything is OK with English values.
Please let me know why I can not upload `.xls` file with Japanese language?

> It's OK when I change file to `.xlsx`!

Comment: AFAIK, It should work without any problem!, Can you please share a sample Excel file? -HTH ;).

Comment: yes, it's ok when i changed to .xlsx :))

Comment: I checked a `.xls` or 97-2000 office document with some Japanese notes and it works fine!!!